# How to change a register value during debugging a Go binary using Delve?

Tags: go, reverse-engineering, delve

Exactly as the question says: During debugging a Go binary, I want to change the value of a register. `help set` in `(dlv)` returns:

`(dlv) help set`

`Changes the value of a variable.`

`[goroutine <n>] [frame <m>] set <variable> = <value>`

`See $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-delve/delve/Documentation/cli/expr.md for a description of supported expressions. Only numerical variables and pointers can be changed.`

I've looked at the documentation but it sounds confusing to me. I appreciate any clarification. I simply need to change the value in a register.

Comment: If you mean "how can I set a machine register": you can't. It says so right in the text you quoted. You can only set a language level variable, and even then, only if it's numerical or a pointer.

Comment: @torek Oh! So that’s what the last sentence in the quote means. Maybe you can add the answer and I’ll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [delve debugger CLI](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/Documentation/cli) `set` command doesn't offer access to machine registers.  You can only set source-code level variables.  The phrase:

> Only numerical variables and pointers can be changed.

means that some source-code variables cannot be manipulated this way, e.g., you can't call most runtime functions.  For instance, even if you have `math/big` and therefore `NewInt`, you cannot use this to build a new `*Int` value.